# Video.js html5 player (version 4.11.3) works in all browsers except IE (8 & 11 tested)

Tags: internet-explorer, video.js

In IE, play button showing only a rectangle. Clicking any part of the poster will play the video, and some skin elements start to show. But certain elements of the skin are missing.

Works fine with Google Chrome, Safari, Firefox.

Problem page: http://haostaff.com/store/index.php?main_page=pazu

Demo html file shows same problem on local machine. How come the same problem does not exist for the demo on the http://www.videojs.com/ site?! Spent whole day in vain.

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe I am the only one having such problem. My search did not find any similar issue reported. Anyone else having the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with videojs css issue for some reason it doesn't work if you were to use the full css locally you have to use the original source for provided at videojs.com. i have made fiddle for you and tested in IE as well its working fine. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vyyqyyyk/)

HTML

```
   <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.11/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.11/video.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  .vjs-default-skin { color: #ffffff; }
  .vjs-default-skin .vjs-play-progress,
  .vjs-default-skin .vjs-volume-level { background-color: #ffffff }
</style>
    <video id="MY_VIDEO_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
 preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg"
 data-setup="{}">
 <source src="http://haostaff.com/store/video-js/pazu.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
 <source src="MY_VIDEO.webm" type='video/webm'>
 <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
</video>
```

Comment: Thanks, Sim, for looking into this. I have implemented your codes. Problem persists! Your fiddle works well in my browser, too (just as the videojs official demo video). But for some mysterious reason, the codes don't work on my site. Check this same page: http://haostaff.com/store/index.php?main_page=pazu, and if you view its source code, you would see that I have religiously implemented the fiddle codes.   Thanks, Jeff

Comment: try removing the sources for sublimevideo that might be causing the issue

Comment: Tried. Still the same problem. Great mystery why official demo works, the fiddle demo works, and my production site does not work - all with the same codes!

Comment: i just checked the page it still have the source for sublime http://prntscr.com/5x58je

Comment: Oh, I added it back after testing, because I need it for my videos on the live home page. This is really not the issue. I can remove it for your testing, if you like. The issue persisted for a long time before I fell back on this sublimevideo option to get things going first. But I would really like to solve this issue so that I can use the Videojs package, as Sublime is giving me some other issues (more tolerable), which I am not sure of being able to resolve. Thanks Sim for your patience.

Comment: I removed the sublime video source from head again for your testing. Please let me know what you see, and then I put it back if it is not the cause. Thanks.

Comment: Found the problem. It is these two lines in the head that was giving me the unique problem: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />  Thanks, Sim, for staying with me to solve this problem!